# Sqlalchemy replacement_traverse is not modifying the query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

My understanding is that the wrapper function passed into `replacement_traverse` should be substituting the element, in this case `FooModel`, with the aliased tablesampled object. However the query returned is identical to the one passed in, even though the output indicates a hit on the `if` and two hits on the `elif`. I would expect that post replacement, my query would see the raw sql change from using `foo` to `foo_1`, the sampled object.

```py
def test():
    """_summary_
    https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg25258.html
    """
    import time
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    from sqlalchemy import Table
    from sqlalchemy.sql.visitors import replacement_traverse
    global session
    
    def wrap():
        _foo_sampled = aliased(foomodel.FooModel, tablesample(foomodel.FooModel, 50))
        print(_foo_sampled)
        def replace(element, **kw):
            """https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg25258.html"""
            if isinstance(element, Table) and element.name == foomodel.FooModel.__tablename__:
                print(f"replacing if-branch {element} {type(element)} {_foo_sampled} {type(_foo_sampled)}")
                return _foo_sampled
            elif foomodel.FooModel.__table__.c.contains_column(element):  # replace columns in the table
                print("replacing elif-branch")
                return _foo_sampled.__table__.c[element.key]
            else:
                print(type(element))
        return replace
    wrapper = wrap()
    
    q = (
        sa.select(sa.func.count(foomodel.FooModel.id), barmodel.BarModel.name)
        .join(
            foomodel.foo_baz_association_table,
            foomodel.foo_baz_association_table.c.foo_id == foomodel.FooModel.id,
        )
        .join(barmodel.BazModel, barmodel.BazModel.id == foomodel.foo_baz_association_table.c.baz_id)
        .join(barmodel.BarModel, barmodel.BazModel.bar_id == barmodel.BarModel.id)
        .where(barmodel.BarModel.name != sa.null())
        .group_by(barmodel.BarModel.name)
    )
    
    print(q)
    
    tic = time.time()
    results0 = session.execute(q).all()
    toc0 = time.time() - tic

    new_q = replacement_traverse(q, {}, wrapper)
    print("\n"*3)
    print(new_q)
    print("\n"*3)
    
    tic = time.time()
    results2 = session.execute(new_q).all()
    toc2 = time.time() - tic
    print(f"{toc0=} {toc2=}")
    print(results0)
    print(results2) #expect to see 1/2 the results with tablesampling of 50
```

**desired**

```sql
SELECT count(foo_1.id) AS count_1, bar.name 
FROM foo AS foo_1 TABLESAMPLE system(:system_1) JOIN
```

**actual**

```sql
SELECT count(foo.id) AS count_1, bar.name 
FROM foo  JOIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a bug in sqlalchemy, but the solution was to change

```py
_foo_sampled = aliased(foomodel.FooModel, tablesample(foomodel.FooModel, 50))
```

to not use `aliased` and just pass the result of the `tablesample`

```py
_foo_sampled = tablesample(foomodel.FooModel, 50)
def sample_host_device(element, **kw):
    if isinstance(element, Table) and element.name == foomodel.FooModel.__tablename__:
        return _foo_sampled
```